# Pushing to bitbucket with libgit2sharp

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I'm trying to use libgit2sharp to push to my repo on bitbucket. I'm trying to do this:

```
repo.Network.Push(repo.Branches[branchName], pushOptions);
```

Everything seems fine, no exceptions are thrown and I get no errors in the callback, but when I check on bitbucket none of my commits are there. Other methods seem to work fine (ie I can create a new branch on bitbucket and then use libgit2sharp to fetch and see that I now have that branch locally). Is there anything that I might be missing here?

edit:

Tried to just make a small sample program to see if I can get this working no go. I don't know if my code will help but here it is:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PushOptions options = new PushOptions();
        Credentials creds = new Credentials();
        creds.Username = "username";
        creds.Password = "password";
        options.Credentials = creds;
        options.OnPackBuilderProgress = Program.packBuilderProgressHandler;
        options.OnPushTransferProgress = Program.pushTransferProgressHandler;
        options.OnPushStatusError = Program.pushStatusErrorHandler;
        Repository repo = new Repository("E:/Ohad/Work/libgitTest");

        repo.Network.Push(repo.Branches["origin/master"], options);

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static bool packBuilderProgressHandler(PackBuilderStage stage, int current, int total)
    {
    Console.Out.WriteLine("packBuilder => " + current +  " / " + total);
        return true;
   }
    public static bool pushTransferProgressHandler(int current, int total, long bytes)
    {
    Console.Out.WriteLine("pushTransfer => " + current + " / " + total +  " , " + bytes);
    return true;
    }
    public static void pushStatusErrorHandler(PushStatusError error)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("error => " + error.Message);
    }
}
```

Just make a new repo on bitbucket and add the above code (changing the stuff thats hard coded) and it should be reproducible. I just made a random change, added and commited it and then used the program to try to push to bitbucket. The output that I am getting from the above is:

```
pushTransfer => 0 / 0 , 12
pushTransfer => 0 / 0 , 32
Press enter to close...
```

The 0/0 looks suspicious to me but I don't know what I'm doing wrong =/. Thanks for any help!!

edit 2:
I just added this:

```
 repo.Branches.Update(repo.Head, delegate(BranchUpdater updater)
        {
            updater.Remote = "origin";
            updater.UpstreamBranch= repo.Head.CanonicalName;
        })
```

to before when I push and it fixed the issue. Not sure exactly why but I'll take it =).

Comment: Without a repro code and a repository against which it doesn't work, I'm afraid it'll be very difficult to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: nulltoken does any of the above help? Thanks =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you're willing to push your **local** `master` branch rather than the remote tracking one.

```
repo.Network.Push(repo.Branches["master"], options);
```

### Update:

> **The branch 'master' ("refs/heads/master") that you are trying to push does not track an upstream branch. **

Provided you have no "origin" remote, the following should work.

```
Remote remote = localRepo.Network.Remotes.Add("origin", url);

repo.Branches.Update(repo.Head,                              -> (A)
    b => b.Remote = remote.Name,                             -> (B)
    b => b.UpstreamBranch = repo.Head.CanonicalName);        -> (C)
```

The code above should be read as *"The branch pointed at by the HEAD **(A)** on this local repository will be, by default, configured to track a branch bearing the same name **(C)** in the distant repository identified by this remote **(B)**."*

Comment: That what I had tried originally but that throws an exception:  The branch 'master' ("refs/heads/master") that you are trying to push does not track an upstream branch.

Comment: This works great. Note, you don't necessarily need to add the remote if it's already added to your git repo.