# How to set a remote using libgit2sharp?

Tags: push, pull, libgit2sharp

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
var origin = repository.Network.Remotes["origin"];
repository.Head.Remote = origin;
```

The only problem is that "Remote" is readonly (I'm using 0.14.1.0). How do i set a default remote for HEAD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'd greatly recommend to update your version, the code below should get your started and work in v0.14.1.

```
Remote remote = repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];

Branch branch = repo.Head;
Branch updatedBranch = repo.Branches.Update(branch,
    b => b.Remote = remote.Name,
    b => b.UpstreamBranch = branch.CanonicalName);
```

See also this **[SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22617675/335418)** which provides some explanation about the branch tracking configuration.